# Delete QListWidget item by text content

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I need to delete a qlistwidget item by text content

I tried:

```
QString mstring =  "Programmer II";

QList<QListWidgetItem *> items = ui->listJobs->findItems(mstring,  Qt::MatchExactly);
    if (items.size() > 0)
        ui->listJobs->takeItem( ui->listJobs->currentRow() );
```

...and various permutations, but I'm missing something. The code above compiles, but does not delete the item from the qlistwidget.

Comment: You can display the values of the other items

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: What are the values of the other items, ie the texts?

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question. If you've solved your own problem, whether inspired by other answers or not, post your solution as an **answer** and roll back the edit on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't indicate what the value of `currentRow` is, but `findItems` doesn't set it, so it's unlikely to correlate with the value you're trying to remove. I don't see any way to use the results of `findItems` and get the row(s) you want to remove. I think you have to loop through the contents, compare the text of each item, and then remove the ones that match. You'll probably want to do the loop in reverse order; otherwise, once you've removed an item, the loop counter will no longer match the list item's row numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by `currentRow`, that's not in the question?

Comment: In the code you've posted, the call is "takeItem (ui->listJobs->currentRow())". That can't possibly be what you want.

Comment: The code I initially posted was based on a complete misunderstanding of the qlistwidget api. The loop I posted, based on your suggestion, works, so thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Your solution is OK as long as there's only one item to find and remove. If there's two or more, this loop will remove the first one correctly, but the others may break. For instance, if rows 10 and 11 need to be removed, row 10 will be removed correctly, and then row 11 immediately becomes a new row 10. But your loop will increment to 11 and never match the row that was formerly 11. You can fix this by reversing the loop and counting down to 0.

Comment: Moved from the initial question: 

Based on @goug 's answer I tested this routine and it works.

    for(int i = 0; i < ui->listJobs->count(); ++i)
     {
        QString str = ui->listJobs->item(i)->text();
           if (str==mstring)
            delete ui->listJobs->item(i);
       }